# Curl PHP parsing hash tags results in 400 bad request

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to crawl a url that has has tag in it but it returns 400 bad request error.

Is there a way to parse this correctly using CURL in PHP?

Comment: Can you show the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anchor fragment (`#` and everything after) is not part of the request URL.  It should never be sent to the server.  cURL has nothing to do with this.  Only the browser cares about this part.

If this page is doing some AJAX or otherwise dynamically loading content based on the anchor fragment, then you will need a browser to run that page and execute the JavaScript.  You can use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) for this task.